# A place composed of many nations and races

Tags: word-request, idioms, expressions

What do you call humorously or in casual English a country / city which is comprised of many races from various provinces of the same country or other countries?
Is there any specific term, expression or idiom to explain a such a place which is made up of many races in which you rarely would find local people who were born there?

Comment: As usual I ask, and not really expecting an answer: "Does a word for this exist in your native language or any other language that you know?" Have you tried a bilingual dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metaphorically a "[melting pot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_pot)"

New York is the typical example of a melting pot, although this is sometimes challenged as there are lots of people with different ethnic backgrounds, but not all groups mix socially.